# Java JScrollPane Not Working as Expected

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jscrollpane, paintcomponent

I have a JScrollPane with a JPanel inside of it. The JPanel is "zoomed" using the following code in the paintComponent method:

```
g2d.translate(this.getWidth()/2, this.getHeight()/2);
g2d.scale(scaleX, scaleY);
g2d.translate(-this.getWidth()/2, -this.getHeight()/2);
```

Now when I "zoom" in and the JPanel is scaled up to the point where it is larger than the JScrollPane I would expect the vertical and horizontal scroll bars to appear, however they do not. I tried to fix this by setting the preferred size of the JPanel to the size of the newly zoomed panel every single time the JPanel is "zoomed", but this doesn't do anything until the JFrame holding the JScrollPane is resized by the user (maybe this triggers a revalidate?). I was hoping someone could tell me what is going on or even a way to get the desired effect. Thanks!

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I tried to fix this by setting the preferred size of the JPanel..

Call `revalidate()` on the `JScrollPane`.

Comment: I called revalidate() on the JPanel and it works properly now, thanks! However, even though this works it doesn't seem legitimate because I am setting the preferred size and revalidating every single time the component is painted. Should I move this or is this perfectly fine? Thanks again.

Comment: *"Should I move this or is this perfectly fine?"*  It is 'perfectly fine'.  Calling `revalidate()` is effectively telling the JRE "Components have been added, removed ore resized.  Layout the container again (making scroll-bars if needed)".

Comment: Thanks for the help, this was definitely the answer to my problem.